# Objective C JSON get value of field in array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, json

I have an array (called results):

```
@interface FourViewController : UIViewController
{    
    NSArray *results;
    NSMutableData *data;
}

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://website/json.php"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];
}
```

When I run this for loop it returns all keys in the array correctly with each JSON string in:

```
int i;

for (i = 0; i < [results count]; i++) {
     NSLog(@"Result: %i = %@", i, results[i]);
}
```

However inside the for loop I need something like this but I cannot find documentation to do it:

```
int i;

for (i = 0; i < [results count]; i++) {
    location.latitude = results[i][lat];
    location.longitude = results[i][long];
    myAnn.coordinate = location;
    myAnn.title = results[i][title];
    myAnn.subtitle = results[i][strap];
    [locations addObject:myAnn];
}
```

lat, long, title and strap are all JSON keys / id's but i cannot access them; is there a way for me to access each key within each iteration inside the array?

Comment: What is `results`? Is it an instance of `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`?

Comment: NSArray I think (in the header file, which is what you are talking about I think? I'm still getting my head around obj-c)

Comment: Even if you declare `results` as an `NSArray`, you might not be getting that at runtime from `JSONObjectWithData` (welcome to Objective C) depending on how the JSON data is structured. You will want to validate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
location.latitude = (double)[[[results objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:lat] floatValue];
location.longitude = (double)[[[results objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:long] floatValue];
```

Hope this helps...

```
myAnn.title = (double)[[[results objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:title] floatValue];
myAnn.subtitle = (double)[[[results objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:strap] floatValue];
```

Comment: Hi there! I will give this a whirl, looks promising :) just out of interest, objectForKey: is that just a JSON instruction or does it apply to normal arrays too?

Comment: Ahh okay thanks! Should the objectForKey key be in quotes as I am getting an error, should it be objectForKey: @"title"; ? thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the help so far! I am getting this error, imagine it is a datatype issue? http://i.imgur.com/50bICTO.png

Comment: do a casting-> like this: (double)[[results objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:lat];

Comment: Thanks again :) getting closer I think now, getting "pointer cannot be cast to type double" :/

Comment: `[[[results objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:lat] doubleValue];`

Comment: @MikeD thanks... your value is returning a string, need to convert it to a double...

Comment: then first print out the value NSLog(@"%@",[[results objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:lat]);

Comment: @Lakesh returning floating point numbers, one of which as an example is: 54.328274

Comment: That has done it! Thanks for this! Just one final question, calling `[self.mapView addAnnotations:locations];` is not adding the annotations, does the map view need refreshing?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're almost there with your answer already, as you mention the word "keys".

Chances are high (and I need to verify this by dropping your code into a test project) that each of the objects in the array are "`NSDictionary`" objects, from which you can get values for the "`lat`", "`long`", "`title`" keys.